# Leave out a term when summing

Tags: numerics, summation

I'm calculating the Madelung constant

$$\alpha = -\sum_{n_1,n_2,n_3}{\frac{(-1)^{n_1+n_2+n_3}}{(n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2)^{1/2}}}$$

Where $n_1,n_2,n_3$ are any element in the integer domain and they can't be zero simutaneously. How can I do this in Mathematica? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sums are conditionally convergent, so you have to specify a summation order that suits your purpose. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant). Since the question seems to be focused on the issue of dropping a term in a sum, here is one way of doing it, without making any claim that the resulting sum is of any use:

```
Chop[NSum[
   If[i == j == k == 0, 0, 
    (-1)^(i + j + k)/Sqrt[i^2 + j^2 + k^2]], 
  {i, -Infinity, Infinity}, {j, -Infinity, Infinity}, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]]
```

Comment: Note that `-Chop[NSum[If[i == j == k == 0, 0, (-1)^(i + j + k)/Sqrt[i^2 + j^2 + k^2]], {i, -Infinity, Infinity}, {j, -Infinity, Infinity}, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns", NSumTerms -> #]] & /@ {15, 20, 25, 30}` gives inconsistent results: `{1.98876, 3.21355, 5.94699, ComplexInfinity}`

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes indeed. THese are my favorite kind of sums - the ones where you get to pick what the answer is...